# How to run GUI program using different user

Tags: c#, process

I have three accounts on Windows 2008: Admin, User1, User2, User3. I would like to run GUI program from Admin account using c# on these User1, User2, User3 accounts. The problem is that while using `Process.Start` with User1 or any other user credentials the GUI app starts on Admin user desktop. I would like to run program on User1 desktop.
I would like to simulate behavior like manually we do: Switch User, Login with User1, Run GUI program. 
Is it possible to do that?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think you can use runas: http://ss64.com/nt/runas.html

Comment: Do you really want to switch user?  How about just impersonating one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/impersonation-in-net

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run the program using different user credentials, if that's what you mean.

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo  
{  
    FileName = "app.exe",  
    UserName = "Username",  
    Domain = "yourdomain or leave blank",  
    Password = "password",  
    UseShellExecute = false, 
};  
Process.Start(processInfo);
```

Comment: This do not work because logged user use HOST USER DESKTOP. Let's say I run HOST app on Admin account. Host app run GUI app with User1 credentials. The launged app will run with User1 credentials but on Admin desktop.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this, i.e. spawning the program on the user's desktop?  Thanks!